# Which firebaseUI library should I use for the realtime database in androidX?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've tried

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'
```

but neither of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [firebaseUi repo on github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-6.0.md) you need to use version 6.0.2 or later for androidX compatibility

```
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.0.2'
```